# How to test a binary, to see if all shared library dependencies, are satisfied?

Tags: linux, dynamic-linking, portability

I have a program which I compiled on an earlier version of Fedora which suddenly broke after an upgrade. I was running an older version of Fedora at the time which had stopped receiving updates; so I decided to upgrade.

What was unexpected was a binary failing to run because of a missing shared library:

```
error while loading shared libraries: libboost_filesystem.so.1.66.0:
cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

The necessary package was installed, but the version had changed:

```
Package boost-filesystem-1.69.0-9.fc31.x86_64 is already installed.
```

The issue was that the program was linked to a specific version of `libboost_filesystem.so`.

I rebuilt the program from source and everything worked fine.

What options are available to me for automated testing of a binary, to see if all shared library dependencies, are satisfied, on a given platform that it's running on?

Comment: You can try `ldd /path/to/binary`  and grep for missing libraries. Another option is to run `dnf provides *libboost_filesystem.so.1.66.0*`  And there is also `rpm -qla | grep somelib`

Comment: The version of `boost-filesystem` in the release of Fedora that you are using is 1.69 whereas the program that you are using needs 1.66 which isn't available from the repos. The easiest thing to do is to create a libboost_filesystem.so.1.66.0` symlink in `/usr/lib64` pointing at 1.69 although it may not work if the changes are too extensive and it will break if 1.69 is upgraded. A better option is to get the source code for 1.66 from Github and compile it and add it to your LD_LIBRARY_PATH.